# How to print full yaml or json object to file with node

Tags: node.js, yaml, swagger

I am trying to copy the definitions portion of a yaml file into a js doc for a codegen project.  I tried using regular expressions (which worked great for copying methods out of swagger generated js files) but apparently regexp does not handle info from yaml files very well.  I managed to print MOST of what I want to the commandline through console.log.  There are a few arrays that just say [Object], which is problematic.  I would like to have their full contents printed.  HOWEVER, this is not the main problem.  When I try to write this output to a file instead of the console...it just says 
"[object Object]
[object Object]"
for my 2 definitions.  Has anyone done anything like this before?  Here is a snippet of my code and what the console output looks like vs the two lines above  TIA!

```
var doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('path to my file\swagger.yaml', 'utf8'));
for(var d in doc['definitions']){
    logit(doc['definitions'][d]); //logit write to consle and a file
}
```

[image]

Comment: `safeLoad` suggests you are using https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml. It has the `dump` method too.

Comment: You should make this an answer so I can give you a green checkmark.  Now I just need to turn the yaml into json.

Comment: To improve your post: Don't use screenshots, include the JSON as text. Don't ask yes/no answerable question about people (anyone done this before?), instead ask an open question about programming (e.g. How can I ....?). Don't include thanks (in advance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`safeLoad` suggests you are using the [js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) library. It also provides the [`safeDump`](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml#safedump-object---options-) and `dump` methods.

```
yamlDef= yaml.safeDump(doc['definitions'][d]);
logit(yamlDef);
```

to convert YAML to JSON:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(yamlDef);
```